# Find and type/ display a random textfile with a batchfile

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hello I'm trying to complete a batchfile im working on.

I have a library of motivational quotes textfiles, and i want my batchfile to pick one random quote textfile and display it in the command window. with the command type i guess.

my path to the folder with the quotes is:

```
 C:\Users\niv\Documents\test\scripts\quotes
```

inside there is :

```
      Quote 1.txt
      Quote 2.txt
      Quote 3.txt.
```

i did the command: `type "C:\Users\niv\Documents\test\scripts\quotes\quote1.txt"
that only displayed the selected quote1.txt ofcourse.

If possible i want to get the selected Quote-text file to be a variable so i can use it for different tasks in my batchfile like:

after receiving the selected quote do this command with a program that makes it possible for my computer to read anything after "". like this

```
%speech% "%quotes%"
```

the %speech% lets my computer speak whats inside the quotation marks.

i hope you can understand what im trying to accomplish here if not just ask :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming each quote is contained in a single line in each file. I recommend placing all the quotes in a single file named quotes.txt, with one quote per line. This should make it easier to maintain the quotes. Then all you need is code that will count the number of lines in the file, and then randomly pick a line between 1 and count.

The FIND /C command can count the number of lines in a file.

The `%RANDOM%` dynamic variable gives a pseudo random number between 0 and 32767, and the modulo SET /A operator can be used to convert the value into a number between 0 and count-1.

The FOR /F command reads lines from a file, and you can use the SKIP option to skip a random number of lines.

**quotes.txt**

```
quote 1
quote 2
quote 3
quote 4
```

**randomQuote.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Count the number of quotes and define a random number to skip
for /f %%N in ('find /c /v "" ^<quotes.txt') do set /a skip=%random% %% %%N
if %skip% gtr 0 (set skip=skip=%skip%) else set "skip="

:: Read a random quote into a variable
for /f "%skip% delims=" %%A in (quotes.txt) do (
  set "quote=%%A"
  goto :break
)
:break

:: Echo the quote (or do whatever you need)
echo %quote%
```

Comment: this worked when I put the batchfile inside the quotes folder. How can I run the batchfile from another location and still get the results. Do i need to set the folderpath to the quotes-folder  in the code? sorry if you don't understand what i mean, im new to this stuff and im trying to learn :)

Comment: @Nivi - prefix the `quotes.txt` with the full path info in both places in the code. If the path includes spaces or special characters then the entire path should be enclosed in quotes. For example: `"c:\your path\quotes.txt"`

Comment: Thank you I did try to add it there, but i missed the second "quotes.txt" in the code thats why i was confused, but this was what made the bits fall into place it works 100% thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read a text file into a variable like this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set filename=Quote 1.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%filename%"') do (
  set quote=!quote!%%a^

)

echo !quote!

endlocal
```

The trailing `^` in `set quote=!quote!%%a^` followed by an empty line ends each appended line with a newline. If you don't need the newlines, you could replace

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%filename%"') do (
  set quote=!quote!%%a^

)
```

with

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%filename%"') do (
  set quote=!quote! %%a
)
```

to get the whole quote in a single line.

In any case you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for this (`!quote!` instead of `%quote%`).

Answer (score 0):

My answer focuses on counting the number of text files in the path you provided, then choosing a random quote number and typing the quote. both of the previous answers can be used as reference for inserting the quote into a variable (which my code does not provide):

```
@Echo off
set path=C:\Users\niv\Documents\test\scripts\quotes
cd /D %path%
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set count=0

for %%a in (*.txt) do (
set /a count=!count!+1
)
echo Total number of quote files: %count%

set /a num=(%count% * %random%) / 32768 + 1
echo Quote #: %num%

type "%path%\quote %num%.txt" 

endlocal
```